# VBA - Listbox shows gridlines after conducting a keyword search

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

My listbox working fine, but when I conduct a word search (screenshot below), some gridlines show up?  Why?  How do I get rid of the gridlines?  Sometimes, these gridlines show up even after I clear the search and re-populate the listbox.  Very strange!  Anyone ran into this problem?

```
Private Sub SetupHoliday_Click()
     On Error Resume Next
     For i = 0 To AppliedYearListbox.ListCount - 1
          If AppliedYearListbox.Selected(i) = True Then
             dateButton = "Date_" & Format(AppliedYearListbox.List(i), "yyyy") & "_" & Format(AppliedYearListbox.List(i), "m") & "_" & Format(AppliedYearListbox.List(i), "d")
             Set foundCell = rangeSearchDate.Find(what:=dateButton, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
             foundRow = foundCell.Row
             Sheets("Background").Range("AF" & foundRow).Value = "Holiday"
             DoEvents
             AppliedYearListbox.Selected(i) = False
          End If
     Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried disabling screen updating in your loop and then re-enabling afterwads? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating

Comment: Hi Yorik... Done as you suggest but still same problem.

Comment: Uhhh.... No replies other than Yorik's?  Huhuhu... These gridlines look so bad!!